# How to skip rerendering a reactive component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component with reactive properties.
I want the properties to be changed and want to know when its changing using any possible event but I don't want to rerender the DOM.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-nonreactive, but as it states in the description, "if you're using this, you may want to rethink your data model." Or try `Object.freeze()`.

Comment: huh? you want to watch for any changes to what? a variable?

Comment: @HBensiali a property

Comment: like data:{'property_name': 'my_name'}   ? you want to watch changes to property_name

Comment: @HBensiali not data but `props` and don't want to render on change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean but vuejs already has several functions to do this.

```
var component_name = new Vue({
     el:'#element_container',
     data: {
         'data_to_be_watched': {'name': 'Abdel', 'surname': 'Sakherdine'}
     },
     watch: {
         'data_to_be_watched.name': function(value){
             //do something with value here
        }
    }
});
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but here's one interpretation of what you're asking for. The component takes a prop for value and one to indicate whether it is paused. It has a data item to cache its value and a computed that will update that cached value to the prop value only when not paused; the computed always returns the cached value.

The upshot is that you can pause DOM updates on the component. When you unpause, it updates and stays updated.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: 'red',
    paused: false
  },
  components: {
    cPausable: {
      template: '<div>{{proxyValue}}, {{paused}}</div>',
      data() {
        return {
          cachedValue: this.value
        }
      },
      props: {
        paused: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        },
        value: {}
      },
      computed: {
        proxyValue() {
          if (!this.paused) {
            this.cachedValue = this.value;
          }
          return this.cachedValue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="value">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="paused">
  <c-pausable :value="value" :paused="paused"></c-pausable>
</div>
```